# Map Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  col1 col2 col3
  | a | 1 | 2 |
```

What I want to do is map each row to replace the `col3` with this function

```
def winner (col2, col3, col1):
    if(col1 == "a"):
        return col2
    elif(col1 == "D"):
        return col3
    else:
        return "X"
```

I tried to map but I can't

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
  | a | 1 | 1 |
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hello, what is your res var ?

Comment: my mistake! corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to define your **mapping function**, you can do it like this :

```
def winner (raw):
    if(raw['col1'] == "a"):
        return raw['col2']
    elif(raw['col1'] == "D"):
        return raw['col3']
    else:
        return "X"
```

Then you can use the `pandas.apply` function to apply your mapping function :

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda row : winner(row),axis=1)
```

And now you have a nice little brand new dataframe :) !